# After deploying the custom Event System code Content Porter is not able to connect with CMS server

Tags: 2013, event-system, content-porter-2013

After deploying the custom Event System code, Content Porter is not able to connect with CMS server. Event System Code is working properly.

In my code I have used AWS reference dll (AWSSDK.Core, AWSSDK.S3).

While connecting to content porter getting below error:-\

```
[Critical]  System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Client.ImportExportServiceFault]: Initialization of the extension 'D:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\bin\Tridion.Event.S3KeyDelete.AWS.dll' failed.
Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (Fault Detail is equal to Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Client.ImportExportServiceFault).
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you please go through https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000007149 which may help you.

Comment: Have you merged this assembly with your es code into a single dll?

Comment: @MarkoMilic After merging the 3rd party dll with project dll, i am getting different error like  "Invalid region name" .Could you please help me on this.

Comment: Can you provide exception details?

Comment: @MarkoMilic Now After merging the 3rd party dll with project dll, merged dll is not able to take the configuration value in app-setting is not coming, so throwing the error. But once i am just putting the project dll, it is able to take the value from app setting. Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still an external reference issue. Previously you had issues with external dll not being merged with Event System DLL. And that is the exception you observed previously. Normally, if you just copy/paste your dll and Event system DLLs in bin folder and start Tridion, Event System might work, but you will observe issues with Content Porter, Core Service, or Template Builder. So you need to merge it with DLL or add it in GAC.

Now, you have issues with reading configuration file. This is most probably because you use reflection to get the location of executing assembly and read configuration file from there. However, that is NOT the case. Tridion "embeds" your dll into its own and executes it in a different place. So for debugging purpose, log where is your executing assembly into log, and try to get its location. That can help you then to identify why app.config is not being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem with assembly probing. To investigate this, you can use Microsoft's Assembly binding log viewer ([Fuslogvw](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer))

This will be different for each distinct process. If this is the problem, then you can either put a copy of the assembly on the probing path of each process, or register it in the GAC.